# What is a good Resource for learning Microsoft Visual C# 2008 coming from QBasic and VisualBasic 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

What is a good resource for learning Microsoft Visual C# 2008 coming from QBasic and VisualBasic 2008?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312292/whats-the-best-c-ebook-for-a-vb-programmer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can more than likely jump into C# with both feet, so to speak, if you're already experienced with VB.NET. The two languages are extremely similar, once you get beyond the curly braces and other syntactical differences. I learned C# mostly from converting VB.NET projects with the aid of some online conversion tools, and looking up anything that I didn't immediately understand the relationship between the two languages. If you don't have anything to convert that you've already written, use some sample code, as you might find on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) or even [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336738.aspx). Along the way, you'll probably amass a library of neat tricks to use on future applications.

I've had very good luck with [Developer Fusion's conversion tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/), and I've used [this one](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/) a few times as well. Additionally, as I think many veteran .NET programmers will tell you, there is no substitute for [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

That leaves you mostly with the battle to learn any differences between coding styles and accepted practices in C# and VB.NET. I don't know where else better to learn that than reading Stack Overflow.

Some eBooks may be of help, like Illustrated C# 2008, which is apparently [available for free](http://www.ebook3000.com/Illustrated-C--2008_18267.html).

As far as a QBasic background, if that's the majority of your experience, the biggest hurdle for the transition to C# is going to be learning Object-Oriented Programming. To truly master any of the .NET languages, you need to have a solid understanding of OOP concepts like objects, classes, abstraction, inheritance, encapsulation, polymorphism, and so on. I don't have any particular titles to recommend here (should be easy to find), just the advice not to neglect a thorough understanding of design patterns as you work through the syntax of the language.

Most importantly, don't be afraid to ask questions! It's how we all learned, whether we admit it or not. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This book is a good start. [PRO C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491)